# Kendo TabStrip, getting error - microsoft jscript runtime error object expected when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I am using the Kendo TabStrip control on my MVC view page.  I have 4 tabs.  I am using a partial view for each tab.  I am using Ajax to render the HTML in each tab.  I am also using jquery in my javascript in each of the partial views.  Initially the tabs load fine, no issues.  I have a submit button on each tab.  When I click the submit button it does a postback to the server, does some work, returns to client and then switches to the next available tab.  When it switches to the new tab, the old tab is returning an error:

**microsoft jscript runtime error: object expected**

I have been researching this issue and have not had any success in finding a resolution.  I am helping you guys can help.

Updated Comments:

I cannot post any code since this is for work.  But I did find out a little bit more about the issue.  First there is no problem with the view or the controller, because the tab control, view and controller all worked together fine before I upgraded from Telerik to Kendo.  Second, the issue seems to be that the tab control is treating the partial view like a regular view, whenever a postback happens.

The code setup for this is real simple.  Kendo tab control and for each tab, I am using a partial view.  On each partial view is a submit button.  When I click the button, I get the error above.  Worked fine for Telerik control, does not work for Kendo.

Comment: Can you post some code? Perhaps your view and controller. There are many possible causes for this error.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for you to post some code, you could look into the following:

1. Are jquery/kendo scripts properly included
2. Using a Telerik supported version of jquery (1.9.1+)
3. Check your javascript syntax

Comment: How do I add code to the question since you cannot cut and paste?  A little confused.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, got fixed by loading the jQuery.unobtrusive-Ajax.js file.

Comment: I am loading this file in the shared Layout.cshtml file.